# How to submit this?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have below piece of code, I am using puppeteer for submitting this content of form, but after entering the value it reloads the page and field get blank and nothing happens, How to submit this?

```
<form name="Logon" method="POST" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return false;"> 
<input type="password" name="textField" title="* textField" id="textField" maxlength="32">
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:submitForm(); return false" tabindex="2">
<img src="/images/btn_submit_def.gif" border="0" alt="Submit" title="Submit"></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Please refrain from putting the same thing in your comment. Also, please edit the question to include what you have attempted so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.form.submit();" tabindex="2">
```

Or, using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit();" tabindex="2">
```

You may also need to replace `href="#"` with `href="javascript:void(0);"`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing few things in your code like - 
1. action attribute(which means what you want to do , when submit gets clicked. 
2. submitform method definition is also missing

Please see below, I updated your code as below -

```
    <form name="Logon" method="POST" autocomplete="off" action="test.php"> 
    <input type="password" name="textField" title="* textField" id="textField" 
    maxlength="32">
    <a href="#" onclick="javascript:submitform(); return false" tabindex="2">
   <img src="/images/btn_submit_def.gif" border="0" alt="Submit" title="Submit"></a>
   </form>

   <script>

   function submitform()
   {
     document.Logon.submit();
   }
   </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
<body>
        <form name="Logon" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="password" name="textField" title="* textField" id="textField" maxlength="32">
            <a href="#" onclick="func(this)">
                <img src="/images/btn_submit_def.gif" border="0" alt="Submit" title="Submit">
            </a>
        </form>
    </body>

    <script>
        function func(ahr) {
            ahr.innerHTML = "very good"
            // you can do whatever you want
        }
    </script>
```